Specialization and Geometric Points
I have the following question regarding specialization of points, and how this translates to geometric points.
First a few definitions. (In what follows the definition of the specialization map isn't really needed, but it's what lead me to ask this question).
Let $X$ be a scheme and $x,x'\in X$.
$\textbf{Definition 5.19.1}$(Stacks Project): We say that $x$ is a $\underline{specialization}$ of $x'$, if $x\in\overline{\{x'\}}$ and we denote it by $x' \leadsto x$.
If $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf on the Zariski topology of $X$ and $x,x'\in X$ with $x' \leadsto x$, we get an induced map on stalks, called the $\textbf{specialization map}$: $sp:\mathcal{F}_x\to\mathcal{F}_{x'}$.
We want to mimic the above construction for sheaves on the on the étale topology of some scheme, and since we wrok on étale we have to work with geometric points of the scheme.
This is done in $\textbf{Section 59.75}$ on the Stacks Project, and it gives us the following:
Let $S$ be a scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ a sheaf on the étale topology of $S$. For $\overline{s}$ a geometric point of $X$ and $\overline{t}$ a geometric point of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}^{sh}_{S,\overline{s}})$, we get a map $sp:\mathcal{F}_{\overline{s}}\to\mathcal{F}_{p(\overline{t})}$, where $p:\mathcal{O}^{sh}_{S,\overline{s}}\to S$ is the canonical morphism.
Now for my $\textbf{Question}$.
With the choice of $\overline{s},\overline{t}$ as before, if we denote by $s$ the image of $\overline{s}$ in $S$, and by $t$ the image of $p(\overline{t})$ in $S$, does it then follow that $t\leadsto s$?
I feel like I can somehow use this Lemma (again from the Stacks Project) to conclude, but I'm not sure I see how.
As seen in a Remark 59.75.3, the opposite holds, i.e. we can lift specializations $t\leadsto s$ to $\overline{s},\overline{t}$ as above.

Hi, please don't use MathJax math formatting to format non-mathematical text - please use Markdown instead.

@KReiser Okay will know for next time! Out of curiosity, why not? Is it for better readability of the "code", or is there a different reason? Or just simply a rule perhaps

Huh, also I guess now that I read Remark 59.75.3 a bit better, I guess my question can be answered positively by using the surjectivity of the map $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}^{sh}{S, \overline{s}})\to\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}{S,s})$, together with my tagged Lemma.

@Fotis Readability of code is one, readability of the document by software (e.g. screen readers) is another.
